# Undefined typescript object properties

Tags: javascript, typescript

this my code

**file.js**

```
const channel = {},
arr = [string,string,string];
for(let i = 0;i < arr.length;i++ ){
    channel[arr[i]] = "Amo" //equal string value
}
```

An array contains only string values. example `["a","b","c","n"]`.
How can I write this code in typescript ?

Comment: `arr: String[] = [..]`

Comment: How can you write *what exactly* in Typescript…?

Comment: How to write my code in typescript ?

Comment: @adiga What did I explain wrong? I wrote js code.I want to convert my code to typescript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference between JS and TS is the concept of strongly typing your code.
In this case, you want to migrate this code from JS to TS, you shouldn't need to do anything as the TS transpiler will be able to infer the types of the variables. If you do wants to enforce the type for the variables, you can do:

```
interface channelObj {
    [key: string]: string
} // This is called index signature and is useful for typing object key-value
const channel: channelObj = {},
arr: string[] = [string, ...];
for(let i = 0;i < arr.length;i++ ){
    channel[arr[i]] = "Amo" //equal string value
}
```